# How to plot many columns against each other in the same line-plot using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, line-plot

Dataset:

[image: Dataset]

I want to use 'Filename' as the x axis, and every column ending with `.csv` as the y data on top of each other.

Hopeful end result:

[image: Hopeful end result]

I am trying to achieve a result like this but so far I have no luck.

```
## packages used
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import re
QtzLOD1 = pd.read_csv (r"doc.csv")

x = QtzLOD1["filename"]
y = QtzLOD1.iloc[0:,1:14]
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], marker=".")

fig=plt.plot()
fig.savefig(p)
```

I am getting keyerror 0
any help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: `df.set_index('filename').plot(legend=False, color='r')`?

Comment: please data sample and full error traceback as text, not image https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12846804 - your issue is not reproducible at the moment. Edit your post to include e.g. `print(df.head())`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without know how your data is structured in the *.csv file. But From my understanding the problem is that x[i] would be a Series, but y[i] can be an slice of the data frame (basically a DataFrame). You may need to use .to_numpy() method to convert it to an array and then working from there. But still you need to pay attention that x and y in plot should be the same size and dimension.
I'm giving you an example that may help, similar to your data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
element=["Be" ,"Na" ,"Ti", "Rb"]
test1=list(np.random.randint(1,1000,4))
test2=list(np.random.randint(1,1000,4))
test3=list(np.random.randint(1,1000,4))
test4=list(np.random.randint(1,1000,4))
test5=list(np.random.randint(1,1000,4))
data=  {"element":element,"test1":test1,"test2":test2,\
"test3":test3,"test4":test4,"test5":test5}
data_frame1=pd.DataFrame(data)
x=data_frame1["element"].to_numpy()
y=data_frame1.iloc[1:,0:]
num_test=len(data_frame1.iloc[0,1:])
for i in range(5):
   y=data_frame1.iloc[::,i+1].to_numpy()
   plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```